# How to Get All Tasks from a Story Using DevOps API

Tags: api, azure-devops, workitem

I'm trying to get all Tasks from a Story with the DevOps API but I only found a relation expand command which is not that what I want.

So how can I "expand" a Story to see all Tasks?

API REQ: https://----/----/----/_apis/wit/workitems/ID?api-version=5.1

With that I only get like the name, desc, state, reason, assignedto and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the related REST API and Azure CLI, it seems that currently we have no easy way to get the list of Tasks that have been linked to a User Story.

You can execute the API "[**Work Items - Get Work Item**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" and get the list of work items that have linked to the specified User Story from the Response body of this API.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand={$expand}&api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

In the list you can get the URL of each linked work item. You can get the detailed information of each work item via sending request to the URL. From the detailed information, you can get the work item type of each item.